# In Python, how to use many exec calls in a shared context?

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python program to execute embedded Python code in Verilog scripts. I thought of using the `eval` and `exec` functions, but I came across a problem: I would like to have all the `exec`s and `eval`s run in the shared *context*, without changing the main program's environment.

I'm putting `exec` and `eval` inside a function to call in the parsing routine:

```py
# some parsing code
for embedded_code_string in list_of_embedded_code_strings:
    execute_embedded_code(embedded_code_string)
# more parsing code
```

```py
def execute_embedded_code(embedded_code_string):
    exec(embedded_code_string)
    # other routines involving io.StringIO for the redirection of stdout which isn't the problem.
```

If the first embedded code string to be run is `row_len = 1`, and the second one is `column_len = row_len * 2`, then when running the second code snippet, `row_len` would be undefined. It's expected: after all, `exec` is running in the context of  the function `execute_embedded_code`, and after the function finishes, the variable would disappear from both `locals()` and `globals()`.

It appears that you can set the local and global namespace for `exec`. However, the changes after running `exec` **wouldn't be preserved in-place**. (**Corrections: the global_dict and local_dict parameter MUST be a dictionary, or it would be ignored. If it were a dictionary, it would be updated in-place.**) Running `globals()` and `locals()` after `exec` would capture the change, but it would also capture the objects in the parsing program, and I wouldn't want the embedded code to inadvertently mess up the parsing program.

So my question is, how would I run many `exec` calls in their shared context, yet isolated enough that they wouldn't have unexpected consequences. No need to think of security, as all the embedded code to the run would be trusted.

I would like to get the individual outputs of each embedded code string, so I don't think joining them together and run it all at once would work.

Comment: Why not to `join` all code lines into a single string (using newline symbols as delimiter) and then `exec` it at once?

Comment: I would like to get the individual outputs of each embedded code string, and joining them together would make this difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to define your own shared `globals` that you pass to `exec` which is then modified by the embedded code:

```
def execute_embedded_code(embedded_code_string, shared_globals):
    exec(embedded_code_string, shared_globals)

shared_globals = dict()
shared_globals['result'] = 0
sample_string = 'result += 1'
execute_embedded_code(sample_string, shared_globals)
print(shared_globals['result'])
```

**Output**

```
1
```

**Note**

To address a comment below, the [documentation for exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) states

> If only *globals* is provided, it must be a dictionary, which will be used for both the global and the local variables.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem! I now knows what I did wrong: I initialized `shared_globals` as `None`, and `exec` did not modify it in place. It appears that you have to init `shared_globals` as a `dict()`.